# iReport Crosstab data problem

Tags: dataset, ireport, crosstab

I am trying to setup a row group in a crosstab within iReport. This row group uses three strings concatenated together. When any one of them changes a new row is made. The problem I'm having is that these three strings are taken and stored in a variable. Once they are in this variable the only way to get at them is to split the variable based on a delimiter, and then display them. It seems that I cannot get at the strings individually without using a delimiter.

I need a different way of getting at these strings. I cannot use a delimiter to split the variable apart because its possible that the delimiter will be in the string more often than I want it to be (giving me more than 3 strings back). But it seems that I can't just use the individual strings because the rows will not print correctly. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping each individual string in its own named variable. Then, create a fourth variable which is defined as the original three strings concatenated together. You should then be able to use that fourth variable in your row group, but still have easy access to the original three strings from any expression in your report.